# After upgrade my Chrome, there are two black point besides the Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap DatePicker in one of my projects.

After:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlQFk.png)

You can find there are two black points at left side.
Can anyone help me to remove it? Thanks!

Comment: These look like bullet points - if you view the CSS in the browser developer tools, you should be able to see what's applying the bulleted style.

Comment: Please add your Chrome version, for future reference. Three dots in the top left corner, help, about.